# Need information on .aep files and related stuffs

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I have never used adobe before and in fact have no experience of Graphics design as such. .

I got an animation developed on freelancers.com. 
As a final delivery they are giving me a .aep file.
The size of the animation they sent me as .MP4 is 17 MB, while the size of  .aep file is only 2.7 MB.

I want to make sure that I have got all raw files, so that in future I can modify them as and when required.  Now I have two questions :

1- The .aep file of 2.7 MB is sufficient to recreate the 17MB .MP4 animation?
Or do I need any pother files?

2- What tools I have to install in my PC?

Comment: These sound like questions you should ask the person who developed the animation for you.

Comment: 1. yes, depends on animation. The right aep doing fractal calculation can generate a infinitely sized mp4. but yes its perfectly normal. Its also normal you need other source files 2. After effects

Comment: If you are going to migrate this, how about http://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Yorik i think this is not a good match for video stackexhange. Anyway its hard to find a home for these questions

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly normal for motion graphics source files be 10-100 times smaller than their source. You can easily get much higher rates than this too.

File size is not a good indicator of feasibility since it tells us nearly nothing. So while the file size you describe is reasonable it tells you absolutely nothing about whether or not you have all sources. To do so you would have to open the after effects project file and try to re-render it.

In itself having sources does not guarantee you can make changes. The changes in animation files can be really hard to do. There have many situations where i have had the full source files and still unable to do changes in timely fashion. This is especially true if you are not familiar with the software or the technique used in the software. The only way you can be sure you can make changes is to try make changes.